# How do you import a FBX/OBJ model into a Babylon scene?

Tags: fbx, babylonjs

I am in the process of learning BabylonJS.

How do you add a 3D model into an already existing BabylonJS scene? I have a scene of a building and I want to add a grand piano into the interior of the building. The piano is a 3d model in OBJ and FBX form.

Thanks!

Comment: https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/how_to_use_assetsmanager

Answer (score 2):

You've got to use the [Assets Manager](https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/how_to_use_assetsmanager).

```js
const assetsManager = new BABYLON.AssetsManager(scene);
const meshTask = assetsManager.addMeshTask('piano task', '', './assets/', 'piano.obj');
meshTask.onSuccess = (task) => {
    const pianoMesh = task.loadedMeshes[0];
    // Do something with the mesh here
}
assetsManager.load();
```

If your mesh is in the .OBJ format, then you'll need to use [babylonjs-loaders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babylonjs-loaders).

Answer (score 1):

Hello you have several options:

- Import it in Blender or 3dsMax or Unity and export it using one of the supported exporters: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/Exporters
- Use the FBX exporter: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/Exporters/FBX
- Use the OBJ loader: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/blob/master/dist/preview%20release/loaders/babylon.objFileLoader.js

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if your question is of some importance still for you but you could also try the very good FBX2glTf converter

https://github.com/facebookincubator/FBX2glTF

It can even handle blend shapes, materials, draco-compression etc. It's easy to build and works very fast. Maybe you give that thing a try.